# Initial evaluation in knockout binding when using mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to use a single page application example (knockout tutorial) and the mapping plugin to create a list of items that a user can click on (select). I need a default item to be selected from the beginning and this is where with the mapping plugin it does not work although it works with the bare knockout. Am I missing something? or How do you tame the mapping plugin?

HTML Part:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: gamePlayers">
    <li class="clickable" data-bind="
              text: playerName, 
              css: { selected: playerId == $root.chosenPlayerId() },                              
              click: $root.selectPlayer">
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS common part :

```
var dataJS = {
    gamePlayers: [{playerId:1, playerName:"Sun"},{playerId:2,playerName:"Moon"}],
    playerActive:1
};
```

JS that does work :

```
function GameViewModel(data) {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.gamePlayers = ko.observableArray(data.gamePlayers);
    self.chosenPlayerId = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.selectPlayer = function (player) { self.chosenPlayerId(player.playerId); };
    self.selectPlayer(data.gamePlayers[0]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new GameViewModel(dataJS));
```

JS that does not work :

```
my.vmPlayers = {};

function MyViewModel (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    self.chosenPlayerId = ko.observable();
    self.selectPlayer = function (player) { self.chosenPlayerId(player.playerId); };
    self.selectPlayer(data.gamePlayers[0]);
}

var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        return new MyViewModel(options.data);
    }
};

my.vmPlayers = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJS, mapping);
ko.applyBindings(my.vmPlayers);
```

Example of how it does not work http://jsfiddle.net/HeroEja/43AtS/

So this binding **css: { selected: playerId == $root.chosenPlayerId() }** is not evaluated on initial page load. Any idea why in much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is caused by this line:

```
self.chosenPlayerId(data.playerActive);
```

because in this context `data` won't be a JS object but **`data` is holding the JSON string itself** so `data.playerActive` will return undefined and your initial selection won't work.

What you need is:

```
self.chosenPlayerId(self.playerActive());
```

because you anyway mapped your data into the `self` with `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);`

And because of the mapping plugin `playerId` will be observable so you need to change your usages accordingly to make it work

So in your css binding:

```
css: { selected: playerId() == $root.chosenPlayerId() }
```

And in your `selectPlayer` method:

```
self.selectPlayer = function (player) {
    self.chosenPlayerId(player.playerId());
};
```

A fixed demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukRB9/).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! How do you track if parentheses are required in the bindings or not?

Comment: If you don't have observable you don't need the parentheses this is the easy part. If you have observables in your binding you don't need the parentheses if you directly use the observable e.g. `css: { selected: someobservable }` but you need to put out the parentheses if you have an expression in the binding like `css: { selected: playerId() == $root.chosenPlayerId() }`.